Error Uncaught SyntazError: Unexpected token '<' al mover aplicacion laravel al servidor apache
Saludos cuento con un problema, movi mi proyecto base de laravel 10 con breeze y livewire a la carpeta htdocs de apache en windows, y al momento de hacer un registro me aparece el siguiente error:

Nota: ya ejecute los siguientes comandos y no se alguno de esos da problema:
npm run build
Php artisan livewire:publish
En app/config/livewire.php agregue la linea:
'asset_url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),
Tambien  ejecute los siguientes comandos:
php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:clear && php artisan route:clear && php artisan view:clear
Esto que menciono es un proyecto base al crearlo con composer, solo instalando dependencias npm, sin agregar codigo, porque tengo un proyecto con el mismo problema.
Gracias de antemano.
